# Ingress rule does not work with Service of type LoadBalancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to add an ingress rule to an internal load balancer. As per the dock it can be redirected to a service. It works as long as the service is "ClusterIP" but goes to infinite redirect when its "LoadBalancer"

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.azure.com
    secretName: aks-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: demo.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: aks-helloworld
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /demo
        backend:
          serviceName: demo-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

https://demo.azure.com  works but https://demo.azure.com/demo doesn’t. Difference is aks-helloworld is a ClusterIP but demo-backend is a LoadBalancer

```
13:33 $ kubectl get services
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
aks-helloworld        ClusterIP      10.0.204.168   <none>         80/TCP         15m
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>         443/TCP        16h
demo-backend   LoadBalancer   10.0.198.251   23.99.128.86   80:30332/TCP   15h
```

Comment: While I don't know the specific answer to your question about the LB, as I can't say that I've tried that specific setup, don't forget you can always create a `demo-backend2` `Service` with the same `ports:` and `selector:` and point your Ingress at _that_, if for no other reason than as an interesting troubleshooting exercise

Comment: According to [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), it sure does look like that `rewrite-target` doesn't do anything positive in your setup; have you tried removing it? Better yet, what are you **trying** to do with it?

Comment: Do you have this annotation ` service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"` on your demo-backend LoadBalancer service?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I tried creating the demo-backend2 with ClusterIP and pointed the ingress still it did not work. removed the rewite-target as well . It just says "The page isn't redirecting properly" i am follwing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls

Comment: @Alex I added the annonation , does not seem to be making any difference. What is it for,

Comment: @Neil you may look it up in here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/internal-lb.md  and the annotation is there. So I guess it is necessary to add that annotation if you want to route traffic from services inside the same VPC

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I don't think it's the problem that one has the type clusterIP and another has the type LoadBalancer. When the traffic coming in through the two ways, they will all redirect to the service, in your case, demo-backend.

See the result of the test on my side:

[image]

Access from the Internet:

[image]
[image]

I do not add the TLS, but I think the traffic will all redirect to the service no matter it has the TLS or not. I just change the command with `--set serviceType="LoadBalancer"` when I install the second application through helm. So you can check if there something wrong with your steps.

But I don't think it's a good way to route traffic both in these two ways to one service. If you use the TLS through Ingress, and it will be no secure when there is the way with LoadBalancer at the same time. Because the traffic will bypass the TLS through LoadBalancer.

**Update**

With your comment, I think you need to create a deployment for your application, and then create a service with it, the file like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: yourImage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: myapp
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
    name: demo-backend 
    labels: 
        app: myapp 
spec: 
    type: ClusterIP 
    selector: 
        app: myapp 
    ports: 
    - port: 80
      name: http
```

The deployment is the basis of the application, the service just accepts the traffic for the pod. So I guess you miss the deployment so that you can access your application.

Comment: I understand your concern about LoadBalancer, I will remove it once the ingress works. I installed the demo app via helm which works but my own app in installed via manifest ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: demo-backend
 labels:
   app: myapp
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 selector:
   app: my
 ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080

Comment: Also for HTTPS do I need to add the following in the service?   - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080

Comment: If you use ingress with TLS to resolve the HTTPS, there no need to expose the port 443 for your application in your deployment. Ingress resolve it for you.

Comment: Ok, got it but when I am giving the mapping for the service which is routing to my deployment its only reaching to the 404 default backend , when I am hitting the route pointing to the service talking to the deployment created by helm, it works. Whats the difference between deployment via helm vs apply manifest

Comment: @Neil Helm is just a tool for Kubernetes like apt or yum for Linux. I think there is no difference except the convenience.

Comment: Yes, I even got the manifest of helm installed apps by kubectl get services aks-helloworld  -o yaml  but could not spot the diff why its not working . I have narrowed down the scope and asked another q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629591/ingress-rule-not-redirecting-to-deployment

Comment: @Neil If the answer works to you, you can accept it.

Comment: Still does not work. I am suspecting something is wrong with tls as it works after I remove the tls and try to access via http. Something could be wrong with annotation ? I have 

    ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'

Comment: @Neil You just need to use the annotation provided in the tutorial. You can try to delete the certificate and create it again.

Comment: Charles Xu, finally we figured it out with TCP dump, answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880257/747456.

Comment: @Neil If it means you cannot use the TLS to redirect to traffic? Or just not need the redirect header?

Comment: I could actually re-direct (like it worked in a simple hello world app) but I had to tell the spring-boot app to ignore the header. I actually don't know the side effects of making that config to false.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you exposing the Service as type "LoadBalancer" if you are using Ingress for the resource? You are essentially hitting a the ingress loadbalancer then hitting another service loadbalancer, which is probably causing this redirect issue.

Comment: Initially the service load balancer was created for internal service to service communication. But as I mentioned in the comments I created a duplicate service with type ClusterIP selecting the same backend .but did not seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the following headers added by the engine controller.

```
X-FORWARDED-PROTO: https
X-FORWARDED-PORT: 443
```

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880257/747456