# Ingress rule not redirecting to deployment

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

### Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: assortment-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: aks-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-service
        backend:
          serviceName: my-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

deployment & service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice
        image: myreg.azurecr.io/my-latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
           - name: http
             containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-auth

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: my-backend
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 selector:
   app: myservice
 ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

However

```
curl https://myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/my-service
```

gives

> default backend - 404

Note myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com already resolves to the ingress controller's public IP

When I create a service with type LoadBalancer with same config, it works with public api.

Comment: does it work if you access it using service internal ip?

Comment: It works when I use the service as LoadBalancer

Comment: ok, two questions, are all these resources in the same namespace? also, do you use self signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your pods are in running state.

or

maybe cause of redirection of too many ports from 80 to 8080.ingress to service to target port.

your config is absolutely right it is simple problem may be pod not running or wait for some time to with clear cache of browser.

Comment: It works when I use the service as LoadBalancer , could be it be something to do with the self signed cert?

Comment: you use cert manager rather then using self sign certificate ...self sign certificate may occur errors

Comment: I pretty much followed this to use letsencrypt https://github.com/fbeltrao/aks-letsencrypt/blob/master/install-certificate-manager.md

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

When you use the TLS with the Ingress, there also two ways for you to use the certificates.

One is that use your own certificate. You can follow the steps in [Create an HTTPS ingress controller and use your own TLS certificates on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls). But for this, you just can access the URL like this:

```
curl -v -k --resolve demo.azure.com:443:yourIngressExternalIP https://demo.azure.com
```

When you use the DNS name that you set in Azure with the Public IP, you can create the certificate like this in your case:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -out aks-ingress-tls.crt \
    -keyout aks-ingress-tls.key \
    -subj "/CN=myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/O=aks-ingress-tls"
```

Then you can sue the command `curl https://myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com`, but it will show like this:

[image]

When you use the browser the access the URL, it will show like this:

[image]

To use another way you can follow the steps in [Create an ingress controller with a static public IP address in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip). I suggest this way. Take a try.

Comment: I had already done this steps as per the tutorial the problem is the ingress works with http when I remove tls section but doesn't when I add the tls and access via https I did a ```kubectl describe certificates aks-ingress-tls``` mapping looks correct

Comment: @Neil Do you mind providing your image? I  need to have a test to find more details about the error. You can also provide the steps that do have done.

Comment: @Neil Do you change the DNS name into yours when you create the certificate through the command `openssl`?

Comment: I can't share the image but I am sure its running fine as I can access via http. when I add cert its a problem. I created a openssl command line and used myapp.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com. Same name I assigned to the public ip of the ingress controller.

Comment: I am trying to repro with a sharable image and will post the command also

Comment: @Neil I don't think the cert will be the problem, can you show the show steps that you do? Maybe you can try to delete them and create again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, when the backend app was accessed via ngix controller the following headers were added

```
X-FORWARDED-PROTO: https
X-FORWARDED-PORT: 443
```

While accessing it via the public IP of the LoadBalancer was not a problem 
The issue could be reproduced  when we add the header

```
curl -v 104.43.164.105 -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
```

Gives 302 Found

These additional headers were not liked by the following spring-boot configuration in application.yaml

```
server:
  useForwardHeaders: true
```

This was fixed by

```
server:
  useForwardHeaders: false
```

or

removing the above configuration altogether.